# InnoDB: What does Data free mean?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-workbench

I have a pretty large Mysql table, over 25GB. When extracting an overview with `Table Inspector` in MySQL Workbench, I noticed the field `Data Free` Because the textfields are not selectable, I'm posting a picture of it. Does it mean some sort of reserved space? Or is it actually free space due to a size limit? Or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does "Data_free" mean?  Not much.  Seriously, there are several areas in a table where there is "free space"; Data_free refers to only one of them:

- An InnoDB block is exactly 16KB; there is almost always some wasted space in a block.
- A block in a BTree is normally between 50% and 100% full.
- Groups of blocks ("extents") are allocated in chunks of 8MB(?).  Your 7MiB is part of one such extent.  You will *very* often see 4, 5, 6, or 7, in spite of the main allocation unit being 16KB.
- If you are talking about the main tablespace (`ibdata1`), Data_free refers to how much space is "free" in it; this is usually a large number.

If you were to `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, the table might, *or might not*, shrink from the current 25.6 GiB; it could even increase!  The 7.0 MiB would probably stay 7, or might change to 4 or 5 or 6.

"Does it mean some sort of reserved space?" -- Partially a fluke of the way it allocates space.  But mostly it is a useless number.  If it is bigger than 7 MiB, then there is *likely* to be some space that could be given back to the OS with `OPTIMIZE` -- _assuming it is `file_per_table`.  But don't use `OPTIMIZE` unless you have both file_per_table and Data_free is a significant fraction of the table size.  (This may occur after a big `DELETE`.)

"Or is it actually free space due to a size limit?" -- Tables under some threshold are allocated 16KB at a time; over that threshhold, they are allocated 8MB at a time.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the number of extents (group of blocks) that are in a chunk?
I am asking because i need to [delete records from a table with 100 million rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189769/).  The goal is to be able to fast delete records older than 4 months.

Comment: @surfmuggle - 8M/16K = 512.  The link points to a Question that you deleted.  Partitioning is optimal for deleting "old" data; walking through (via the PK) in chunks of 1000 rows may be second best.  You have seen [_my deletion discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to your blog post. My trouble is that i do not know what needs to be done before any actions are taken. My question is kind of broad and therefore i assume it is not a good fit for SO. I posted it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295009/ but am still unsure if it is good fit because of the broad nature of the question.

Comment: Each "Partition" in a "table" is effectively a "table".  That is, `DROP PARTITION` is quite efficient at freeing the disk space.  The discussion of "extents" is mostly irrelevant.