# Delete large number of rows and change index - what steps in which order and things to watch out for

Tags: mysql, index, delete, mysql-8.0

We daily collect data with multiple records per second. The table `my_xpa_data` has currently close to 100 Million rows and is growing fast.

- table size around 8 GB (used to be 4 GB a couple of days ago)
- index size around 10 GB (used to be 4 GB as well)

I executed a few delete commands affecting only a couple of thousand rows. Then i got greedy and tried to delete around a million rows at once `DELETE from myTable WHERE ID < 100276673`. After 45mins i aborted the action.

The table looks like this

```
| ID  |    id_external    | date_collected      | prg | spotName  | ID_Machine| q_result |
|=====|===================|=====================|=====|===========|===========|==========|
| 127 | 20201229231513000 | 2020-12-29 23:15:13 | 110 | 008-04232 |    95     | 0.986879 |
| 128 | 20201229231515000 | 2020-12-29 23:15:15 | 109 | 008-04232 |    95     | 0.986879 |
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `my_xpa_data` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_external` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_collected` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `prg` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `spotName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `ID_Machine` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `q_result` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `ID_Machine` (`ID_Machine`, `spotName`),
    INDEX `idx_qresult` (`q_result`),
    INDEX `idx_xpa_idmachine_prg` (`ID_Machine`, `prg`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=223323358
```

Based on [Rick James Post MySQL Big DELETEs](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) i am aware that a big delete does require some preparation.

To reduce the space needed and to improve the query speed i wonder what should be changed

1. get rid of indexes that are not needed (for example `idx_qresult`)
2. may be split up date_collected into three columns: YEAR+Month (`YYYYMM`), Day (`DD`), Time (`HH:MM:SS`) or leave it out altogether because id_external has likely the same information
3. the table id_external is a timestamp (`YYYY MM DD HH MM ss SSS` example `2020 12 29 23 15 13 000`) as far as i can tell the last three digits `SSS` are always zero.
4. move the combination of `spotName`, `ID_Machine` and possibly `prg` into a different  table and reference it with an id

Old records can be deleted but some aggregates (average, median) must be kept for some time.

#### Requirements

- Keep every record from the last weeks (if feasible likely 12 weeks)
- Calculate and keep aggregates (average, median, [quartile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209608/)) after 12 weeks (hourly, daily)

#### Question

I am at a loss how to proceed / to start

- Switch of binary logs (anything else?)
- create a new table or tables to receive the records from my_xpa_data
- Regarding columns: Do you know if splitting date_created into three columns (YYYYMM, DD, HH:MM:ss) makes it faster to delete all records for a certain month (202006) without using partition?
- Does it make sense to use helper tables for date_created that contain Year and Month (id, YYYYMM) days (id, DD) and time (id, hhmmssSSS) only store the ids as a reference?
- SELECT Copy rows from `my_xpa_data` into the new table(s)
- Drop the old table `my_xpa_data`
- Create a view named `my_xpa_data` so that our source code  does not need to change much unless [using a view to insert records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825941/is-it-possible-to-insert-data-into-a-mysql-view) is a bad idea?

Comment: why not simply rename them after deleting the old ones

Comment: If it is better to distribute the records in two tables then the view is needed so that a select matches the old table layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overflow...**

Not relevant to the question, but you have disaster coming in a few weeks:  `INT UNSIGNED` will overflow at about 4 billion.  `DELETEing` rows will *not* prevent this.

Plan A:  Get rid of the AUTO_INCREMENT PK *if* you have some other column(s) that is unique and could be used as the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Plan B:  Change it to `BIGINT`.  Better *now* than when the table gets bigger.  (That is 4 bytes bigger, but do it if you must.)

Note: You can run it this way without losing the old table.  This lets you make a mistake without losing data.  (Eventually `DROP` the old table.)

**Deletes...**

Deleting a million rows, especially while the table is active, will take a long time because of needing to save them in case of ROLLBACK or crash recovery.  The simple solution is to delete only 1000 rows at a time.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Since you want to delete "old" rows, `DROP PARTITION` is an excellent option.  But it takes some setup.  See that link (and another page that it points to).
Since you want 12 weeks, I recommend 14 weekly partitions.

**Aggregates...**

Build and maintain a "summary table" by hour.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

That will make the 'report' queries *much* faster.

**Size...**

Here are some suggestions on shrinking the disk space for the 'Fact' table.  That will indirectly help performance some.

`spotName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL` looks bulky.  Can it be normalized?

`DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; do you need 16 digits of precision?  Or would a 4-byte `FLOAT` with 7 digits of precision suffice?

Get rid of most of the indexes once you build the summary table(s).

With rare exceptions, do *not* split up a date into its component parts.  It leads to extra hassles in the code, performance hits, and may even increase disk usage.  (Note that there is overhead for each column.)

`YYYY MM DD HH MM ss SSS` looks like 17(?) bytes.  `TIMESTAMP(3)` is only 7 bytes.  If `SSS` is always 0, then use a 5-byte `TIMESTAMP`.  If you don't want to switch to `TIMESTAMP`, then consider `DECIMAL(17,0)`, which will take 8 bytes and still look like a 17-char string or 17-digit number.

`INT` takes 4 bytes.  Check out the smaller options.  (I suspect you don't need millions of machine ids.)

**VIEW...**

In MySQL, a `VIEW` is essentially syntactic sugar.  No space is saved.  No performance is saved.  Etc.

**Rebuild...**

To delete rows and add partitioning:

1. Create new table with partitioning, changed indexes, different datatypes, normalization, etc
2. `INSERT INTO new-table SELECT revised-columns FROM existing-table WHERE id > ...

Note that the `WHERE` indirectly does the `DELETE` (by copying over only the rows that are to be kept).  That helps things run faster shrinks the result table size and defragments.

**More...**

After you have dealt with most of my suggestions, start a new query and we can discuss the index(es) and summary table(s) further.  Do include the main `SELECTs`.

Comment: From "`spotName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL looks bulky`. Can it be normalized?" i 
 i understood you recommend to move the spotName in a different table (ID, spotName) and in the fact Table `my_xpa_data` only keep a reference to the id?

Comment: You wrote `SELECT revised-columns FROM existing-table WHERE id >`  and  "`WHERE` indirectly does the `DELETE`". Two questions: Can the column be altered live? In pseudo SQL: `ALTER col_A from Type DOUBLE  to FLOAT`? By `WHERE indirectly does the DELETE` do you mean that after an Insert a delete should be executed?

Comment: @surfmuggle - Yes, another table like that.  And make `id` a suitable size (eg, `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` has a limit of 64K and takes 2 bytes).  Many of the useful `ALTERs` cannot be modified "live", but will require prevent writes to the table.  If you can't take any downtime, read about `pt-online-schema-change`.  I cleaned up the cryptic wording.